Modeling a short 10mm wire for RF
This is related to another question of mine looking for parasitics which need to be added to prevent oscillations in simulations .
How should I model a short 10nH wire (say AWG 20 with 0.8 mm diameter about 10 mm long) for proper dissipation at 300 MHz?  You can just consider a 5 mm diameter loop of wire if that is easier to analyze.
Many inductor models use a parallel dissipation resistor included in my simulations as "LRP":

But, I think significant LRP is really only physical for high-permeability materials with eddy/core losses.  In my case, LRP of 100\$\Omega\$ stops the oscillation (like reality), but 1000\$\Omega\$ does not.  But, I cannot physically justify anything below or even near 1000\$\Omega\$.  Is there any way for me to explain a lower LRP for a simple air loop?  I also often see RF tank circuits on the oscilloscope dying out faster than expected (i.e., a low "Q factor") which might be related to the same bad understanding of wires...
Generally, what is the best RF model for wires and package leads at 300 MHz?
By the way, I believe radiation resistance is not important because my layout is all very tight (much less than the wavelength).  Also, the 0.5\$\Omega\$ "LRS" series resistor is actually far higher than expected for 300 MHz (considering "skin effect"), but it still is not high enough to prevent oscillations.
